# Show $T(x+iy)=2x-y+i(x-3y)$ is not a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So i tried by using the properties of linear transformations.
$$\alpha T(x+iy)=\alpha(2x-y+i(x-3y))=2(\alpha x)-(\alpha y)+i((\alpha x)-3(\alpha y))=T(\alpha(x+iy))$$

and 
$$T(x+iy)+T(u+iv)=2x-y+i(x-3y)+2u-v+i(u-3v)$$
$$=2(x+u)-(y+v)+i((x+u)-3(y+v))$$
$$=T((x+iy)+(u+iv))$$ Which seems to indicate that this is a linear transformation. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I've changed that line, This question comes in the context that if you interpret the complex numbers as $C$ then $T$ is not linear but if you interpret them as $R^2$ then $T$ is linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this may just be a poorly-stated question.

This function is definitely linear, when you view $\mathbb{R}$ as the base field (that is, when scalar multiplication allows only real scalars).
In your computations above, you treated $\alpha$ as a real implicitly, by assuming that it directly multiplied through the real and imaginary parts.

However, it is not a $\mathbb{C}$-linear function.

How so?  If it were linear, then you would certainly need to have that $T(i\cdot1)=i\cdot T(1)$.  However, $T(1)=2+i$, so that $i\cdot T(1)=-1+2i$.  On the other hand, $T(i\cdot 1)=T(i)=-1-3i$.

Comment: Thanks! Was a real help

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that $T(i) =-1-3i $, $T(-1)=-2 -i$ and therefore $T(-1)=T(i\cdot i) \neq iT(i)$. So, it is not linear over $\mathbb C$. On the other hand it is linear over $\mathbb R$.